# how to make right justified columns and float 2 decimal places

Tags: java

I wrote a program and everything else seems to work, except I can't figure out how to make right justified columns and float only 2 decimal places with in the code that I have.

Coding "%.2f" makes the string appear as is in one of the columns - it replaces variables.

i.e : System.out.printf ("%-20s %-15s %10s %n" , "%.2f", num2, square2, sqrt2);

I do have columns, but they aren't right justified.

My code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;  
public class SquaresIn {

    public static void main (String[] args)  
    { 
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);    


        System.out.println ("Please enter 3 integers, separated by spaces:");


        System.out.printf ("%-20s %-15s %10s %n" , heading1, heading2, heading3);

        System.out.printf ("%-20s %-15s %10s %n" ,  num1, square1, sqrt1);

        System.out.printf ("%-20s %-15s %10s %n" ,  num2,  square2, sqrt2);

        System.out.printf ("%-20s %-15s %10s %n" , num3,  square3, sqrt3);




        sc.close();
    } // main method 

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this would do the trick:

```
    System.out.printf("%20s %15s %15s \n", heading1, heading2, heading3);

    System.out.printf("%20s %15d %15.2f \n", num1, square1, sqrt1);

    System.out.printf("%20s %15d %15.2f \n", num2, square2, sqrt2);

    System.out.printf("%20s %15d %15.2f \n", num3, square3, sqrt3);
```

Produces following output:

```
          Number          Square     Square root 
              11             121            3,32 
              17             289            4,12 
              19             361            4,36
```

- %f is used for formatting floating point numbers, .2 means 2 decimals
- if you use negative numbers like %-20s, it means left alignment, positive are for right alignment.

EDIT:
- use %d for integer values.

Comment: Also declare square1, square2 and square3 as int, since the square of an int is an int.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
System.out.printf ("%-20s %-15s %10s %n" , heading1, heading2, heading3);

System.out.printf ("%-20s %-15.2f %.2f %n" ,  num1, square1, sqrt1);

System.out.printf ("%-20s %-15.2f %.2f %n" ,  num2,  square2, sqrt2);

System.out.printf ("%-20s %-15.2f %.2f %n" , num3,  square3, sqrt3);
```